# php set path using preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm creating a very simple file browser, and am trying to limit the path to be `/local/ANYTHING`, but NOT `/local` it's self. (where ANYTHING can be any subfolder).

Currently I'm using:

```
$path = (strpos($path, '/local/') !== false) ? $path : "/local/ud";
```

But this accepts `/local/` as the path.  The aim is if its not `/local/ANYTHING` then set it to `/local/ud`.

I've tried to use `preg_match()` and set it as `/local/*` but again this allow access to `/local`.

Is there any way to say the path can only be `/local/ANYTHING` while excluding `/local itself`?

Comment: you can try `\/local\/.+` https://www.regex101.com/r/eI7eS9/3

Comment: or even better: `/local/?+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This forces at least one letter after /

```
preg_match("/\/local\/\w.*/", $input, $output);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fB2

Edited to add \w to make sure you cant be at `/local/`  <- there is supposed to be a space after /

Maybe this is even better?   `"/\/local\/[\w|\d].*/"`
One letter or digit then anything

Comment: Great that seems to work. Thanks for the link, that will come in handy.

Comment: @Tom you're welcome did you see my edit with letter or digit?

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular expression should work for you.
Here is one flavour of it:

```
    <?php
        $path   = preg_match("&(\/local\/)(.+)&", $path)? $path : "/local/ud";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why regex?  There are path/directory tools:

```
if(dirname($path) == '/local' && basename($path) != 'local'){
    // path is good
}
```

Or:

```
$path = (dirname($path) == '/local' && basename($path) != 'local') ? $path : '/local/ud';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need delimiters surround your regexp pattern. Since there are slashes in your path string, another delimiter than the default `/` is applicable, e.g.`~`. The `*` is a quantifier, not a wildcard. It matches 0 or more occurrences of the preceding character. A dot is a special symbol that matches any character. Brackets define a set of characters. A leading`^` inverses the set, i.e. "not": `[^abc]` means any character but a,b,c.

Since file names in many nowadays file systems can contain almost any character, we take the condition: "only one slash after local, accept any number of succeeding characters".

```
"~/local/[^/].*~u"
```

The modifier `u` after the end delimiter makes the pattern UTF-8 compatible.